# How can I override toString for my List implementation?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Beginner question. I have a minimal List implementation:

```
sealed trait MyList[+A]

case object Nil extends MyList[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]

object MyList {

  def apply[A](as: A*): MyList[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) Nil
    else Cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

  private def toString(l: MyList[Any]): String = {
    def f(l: MyList[Any]): String = {
      l match {
        case Nil => "]"
        case Cons(x, Nil) => x.toString + "]"
        case Cons(x, xs) => x.toString + ", " + f(xs)
      }
    }

    "[" + f(l)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(toString(MyList(1, 2, 3)))
  }
}
```

The output of this program is `[1, 2, 3]`. Is it possible to get the same output without explicitly calling the private method `toString()`? That is, to make this the default print output when calling println.

I have tried to add this overriding method:

```
override def toString: String = ...
```

But I ran into two problems. The first is that it's not actually affecting the output of `println`, no matter what this overriding method returns (even though `println` ultimately calls `toString`). The second is that I don't know how to print the list content without a parameter for the list itself (`toString` does not take any parameters, so I assume it must reference `this`, or something else?).

Comment: When you say overriding `toString` doesn't work, can you show us the code you tried? Where did you put the override?

Comment: @GaëlJ I put the method `override def toString: String = "x"` in `object MyList { ... }`. Is this the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, `object MyList` and `trait MyList` are 2 different classes in runtime, also `case class`/`case object` creates its own `override def toString` by default so if you want to override `toString` in both `Nil` and `Cons` i would suggest putting `final override def toString` in `sealed trait MyList[+A]` to make sure it is respected.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thank you, I've got it working by putting it in the `trait` and calling `toString(this)`. If you want to answer the question I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object MyList` and `trait MyList` are 2 different classes in runtime, so whether you put `toString` in one or the other changes what will be overriden

```
sealed trait MyList[+A] {
  override def toString = "x"
}

case object Nil extends MyList[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]

object MyList {
  // ...
 
  override def toString = "y"
}
```

```
println(Nil)
println(Cons("string", Nil))
println(MyList)
```

Additionally `case class`/`case object` creates its own `override def toString` by default so if you want to override `toString` in both `Nil` and `Cons` I would suggest putting `final` before `override def toString` in `sealed trait MyList[+A]` to make sure it is respected.